# pip configured with location that require TSL/SSL

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I am trying to configure a shared hosting server to work with Django. When I attempt to install Django using pip, I get a warning that says

```
pip is configured with locations that require TSL/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. 
...

There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available
```

Understandably I don't have root permissions, so I had to install openssl locally. How should I tell pip where to look for it? Would that actually solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) answer

You can ignore the https by using index-url and passing the http url as a parameter then set it as the trusted source.

```
pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org  package_name
```